# Connect to Oracle with MVC 3 Query and Display Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-3, oracle

I am supposed to create a MVC 3 Page (using Telerik).
I created the application before in C# .aspx 4.0 and worked just fine but my company would prefer to have it as a MVC page.

I never used MVC but I think I got the general hang of it; however, I seem to fail on the simplest step.

I want to connect to an oracle database, query the database and finally display the Data in a Grid. I do not understand how to connect to the database. (I read through approx. 50 Tutorials and couldn't find anything helping me here)

In the webform I would write something like this in the Code behind:

```
OleDBConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection();
dbConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
dbConnection.Open();

OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand();
dbCommand.CommandText = "select * from table where id > 500";
```

And so on. Then write the Data into a DataTable for Example.

So to my question: How would i do this in MVC? I understand that I would put that somewhere in the Model but that is all that I got so far.

---

For further discussion:

Part of the Menu:

```
...
.Items(item =>
{
item.Add().Text("Run Table Statistics").Action("Standard", "TableStatistics");
...
```

Now I would create a Folder DLA and add a new class to it:

```
public static IList<Tiles> GetTiles()
{
   //Write code to get data from your favorite db.(Oracle/SQLServer/..?) 
   //All you want to do is return a list of customer objects
}
```

<- What do you mean by Objects? How could I retrieve objects? I was going to read through the database and add it to a DataTable or similiar.

Now I would create an empty Controller called "TableStatisticsController.cs"
where I put this:

```
public ViewResult Standard()
{
  Object Tiles=**YourDataAccessClass**.GetTiles().ToList();
  return View(Tiles);
}
```

What do you mean by YourDataAccessClass would that be the Class I created in DLA?

You said in my strongly typed view? I would like to use Telerik Grid View, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data access method  does not have to do anything with **MVC Architecture**. It (data access method) can be anything. `MVC` does not care whether you are quering a SQLServer data base / Oracle database. Just wrap your dataaccess method to a method and let your code (action methods in your Controllers) call it. Pass the data back to your view using viewModels/Models or so...

Assuming you are going to wrap your data access code which returns a list of customer object like this

```
public static IList<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
   //Write code to get data from your favorite db.(Oracle/SQLServer/..?) 
   //All you want to do is return a list of customer objects
}
```

You may call this from your Action method like this

```
public ActionResult GetCustomerList()
{
  var customers=YourDataAccessClass.GetCustomers().ToList();
  return View(customers);
}
```

and in your strongly typed view which is binded to List of Customers

```
@model IList<Customer>    
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <p>@item.FirstName</p>
}
```

**EDIT : Based on the Question edit**

> What do you mean by Objects? How could I retrieve objects? I was going
>   to read through the database and add it to a DataTable or similiar.

object of your Model/Entity classes like Customer/ Order etc.. Instead of returning a datatable, i would return a populated Customer/Order object.

> What do you mean by YourDataAccessClass would that be the Class I
>   created in DLA?

Yes. That is correct.

> You said in my strongly typed view? I would like to use Telerik Grid
>   View, is that possible?

Yes it is possbile. But i never used it. You need to look into their documentation.

I recommend you to download some [sample MVC applications](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) and understand how it works.

Comment: Ty, i mark you as the Answer. I was wondering though, where do I put the first Block of Code? Into a Class in the Model folder?

Comment: @PatrickUllrich: What you mean bt First block of code ? The data access ?you can add that to a class in same project or add in seperate class library etc.. completely up to you. I suggest you yo refere some sample projects in the internet

Comment: Check out my Question, I appended more details

Comment: @PatrickUllrich: See my update. It is not a good practice to ask another question in a question. I encourage you to look into some sample applications and understand how MVC works.

Comment: Thx and I will keep that In mind. How would I ask another question correctly?